# Why derived class overloaded delete operator called?

Tags: c++, inheritance, delete-operator

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A 
{
    virtual ~A() {  cout << "~A ";};
    void operator delete(void* p) 
    {
        cout << "A :: operator delete" << endl;
    }
    
    void operator delete[](void* p) 
    {
        cout << "A :: operator delete[]" << endl;
    }
};
struct B : A 
{
    ~B(){ cout << "~B ";}
    void operator delete(void* p) 
    {
        cout << "B :: operator delete" << endl;
    }
    void operator delete[](void* p) 
    {
        cout << "B :: operator delete[]" << endl;
    }
};
int main() 
{
    A* ptr1 = new B;
    A* ptr2 = new B[2];
    delete ptr1;
    delete [] ptr2;
}
```

Output:

```
~B ~A B :: operator delete
~B ~A ~B ~A A :: operator delete[]
```

When deleting the base class pointer ptr1, the derived class delete operator method is invoked, however when deleting ptr2 (which holds the dynamic memory location of the derived class array), the base class delete operator method is used. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: It's undefined behavior to delete an array through a pointer to base class, even one with a virtual destructor. Arrays are not polymorphic the way individual objects are.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  if array are not polymorphic then why derived class destructor called first ?

Comment: @Hardik *why derived class destructor called first ?* -- Undefined behavior means just that -- the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I took your code and ran it in Visual Studio 2022.  The output is: `~B ~A B :: operator delete` -- `~B ~A ~B ~A B :: operator delete[]`.  That is a different output than yours, illustrating what undefined behavior is all about.

Comment: `A* ptr2 = new B[2];` is __dangerous__ when `B` is larger than `A`, since any pointer arithmetic (such as indexing) will be completely undefined.  Never let array pointers convert to their base pointers.

Comment: @TobySpeight   It's also undefined behaviour if `B` is the same size as `A`.   I'd argue that case is even more dangerous, since - despite being undefined behaviour - it is perfectly feasible that the program *seems* to work (e.g. program passes tests, doesn't crash, etc) until something changes (different compiler, installed on another machine, end user running the program instead of developer, etc etc) and it unexpectedly stops working.  Such lurking flaws that are exposed over time tend to result in annoyed end users (customers!) and frustrated developers.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. "Seems to work almost but not quite as I expect" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: I got even different behavior from the OP's output, or Paul's output.  `~A ~A A :: operator delete[]`.  I was hoping for a crash from the sanitizers, but alas, this UB went under the sanitizer's radar.